# c# add null if property in an object does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following response structure which will be serialized following an API call.

```
public class Details
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int maxTry { get; set; }
    public int minTry { get; set; }
    public List<Details> aggr { get; set; }
    public List<string> features { get; set; }
    public string zone { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Root
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following array of objects which is an API response.

```
"result": [
    {
        “maxTry: 17,
        "minTry”: 10,
        "details": [
            {
                “firstName”: “Sam”,
            },
            {
                "firstName”: ”Julio”,
            }
        ],
        "aggr": [
            “Abc”,
        ],
        "zone": “D3”
    },
    {
        "aggr": [
            "Abc",
        ],
        "zone": “C3”
    },
    {
        "aggr": [
            "Abc",
        ],
        "zone": “B2”
    },
  ]
}
```

The problem is even though some objects does not have `maxTry` and `minTry` property in the response, when I deserialize the response as follows,

```
var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(res);
```

I am still getting the output with `maxTry` and `minTry` defaulted to 0. Can this be instead defaulted to `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, make them nullable ints by putting a question mark after `int`

```
[JsonProperty("maxTry")] //newtonsoft
public int? MaxTry { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("minTry")]
public int? MinTry { get; set; }
```

<sub>The JsonProperty attribute let's you name your c# property differently to the json, so you can keep c# naming conventions regardless what the json looks like. If you use System.Text.Json it's JsonPropertyName instead</sub>

The reason why your ints are coming out as 0 is that ints are value types, which essentially means they must have a value and cannot be null. The default value for an int is 0; even if you never set a value for MaxTry it would have a value of 0

```
var r = new Result();
Console.WriteLine(r.MaxTry); //prints 0
```

Nullable ints are harder to work with, because they might be null; you'll need to check `if(r.MaxTry.HasValue)` if you want to see if it's null or not before you do some things with them. To some degree you might want to reconsider leaving them as ints and treating 0 as them having been absent. It might work quite well for your context for example:

```
for(int try = 0; try < result.MaxTry; try++)
```

This won't run if MaxTry is 0.. if that's a problem then you need to decide if maxtry being 0 is ever valid and if it's not, provide some other sensible default if it is 0

Answer (score 1):

Change those properties to `nullable int`

```
    public int? maxTry { get; set; }
    public int? minTry { get; set; }
```